# How to remove underline from gridview buttonfield?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, buttonfield

I have a GridView ButtonField and would like to remove the underline.  The FontUnderline="False" does not work!  I also tries adding text-decoration:none; to the CssClass and that does not work either.

```
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField="OSTA_OrderStatus" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
     HeaderText="File <br /> Status">
     <HeaderStyle Width="6%" />
     <ItemStyle CssClass="sessionOrderDownloadItems" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:ButtonField>
```

My CssClass is coded as follows:

```
.sessionOrderDownloadItems
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    height : 18px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align : center;
}
```

Thank you,
Jim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
 <asp:ButtonField Text="test" ControlStyle-Font-Underline="false" />
```

Works on a test project for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.sessionOrderDownloadItems
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    height : 18px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align : center;
} 
.sessionOrderDownloadItems > a
{
   text-decoration : none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer also.  I will add this to my toolbox!